# Where do I find the keys for multi-part components for use when extending the Chakra UI theme

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, chakra-ui

After reading the documentation I have discovered certain prebuilt components in Chakra ui are composite or "multipart" and in order to style them in an extended theme specific object keys are required to apply the styles; like so:

```
    export const Checkbox = {
  baseStyle: (props) => ({
    label: {
      color: "black",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    icon: {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "mainPurple",
    },
    control: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    container: {
      bg: "lightGray",
      p: 3,
      w: "100%",
      _hover: { bg: "mainPurpleTransp25" },
    },
  }),
};
```

So in the above example keys are label, icon, control, and container.

Where can I find a reference for what these keys are as at present in am trawling through forums to try to find them and in some cases guessing them. I need to style text inputs and dropdowns in addition to the above checkbox.

I have checked for a default theme object in node modules, looked through the documentation and checked their repo but I can't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are looking for this:

[image]